# Closure array parameter in function

Tags: arrays, swift, function, parameters, closures

I need to make a function that takes in an array of buttons and an array of closures. In the end, I am aiming to attach to each button an action from the array, and set up each button in my notification. Here's my function:

```
func makeButtons(buttons: [UIButton], withActions actions: [() -> Void]){

    var bottomAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?
    bottomAnchor = notificationView.bottomAnchor

    buttons.forEach({ (button) in
        button.actionHandle(controlEvent: .touchUpInside, action: actions[buttons.index(of: button)!])

        notificationView.addSubview(button)

        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor!, constant: -20).isActive = true
        button.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: notificationView.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        button.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: notificationView.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

        bottomAnchor = button.topAnchor
    })
}
```

I am indeed using an extension to be able to add a closure for UIButton target using actionHandle(). I got it off Stack. Here's that:

```
extension UIButton {
    private func actionHandleBlock(action:(() -> Void)? = nil) {
        struct __ {
            static var action :(() -> Void)?
        }
        if action != nil {
            __.action = action
        } else {
            __.action?()
        }
    }

    @objc private func triggerActionHandleBlock() {
        self.actionHandleBlock()
    }

    func actionHandle(controlEvent control: UIControlEvents, action:@escaping () -> Void) {
        self.actionHandleBlock(action: action)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(triggerActionHandleBlock), for: control)
    }
}
```

Also, here's how I'm using the make Buttons function:

```
func setButtonsWithAction(){
        let button1 = UIButton()
        let button2 = UIButton()

        addButtons(buttons: [button1, button2], withActions: [self.sayHi, self.sayGoodbye])
    }

func sayHi(){
            print("Hi there")
        }

func sayGoodbye(){
    print("Goodbye")
}
```

All sets up ok, just as I want. However, the problem I am facing is that regardless on which button I click, it performs the last function from my closure array. So in this case it prints "Goodbye" regardless of which button I click.
What I need is:

```
click button1 -> print Hi
click button2 -> print Goodbye
```

What is the problem, I can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

This should definitely show you the way. 
Let me know how it goes.

```
fileprivate func toolbarButton(title: String, closure: Selector ) -> UIButton {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    button.tintColor = .darkGray
    button.addTarget(self, action: closure, for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}
```

use like this:

```
lazy var nearButton = toolbarButton(title: "Near Me", closure: #selector(handleToolButtonNear))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I already got this part though. What want is a function to take in arrays of buttons and arrays of closures, then add the closure to the button with the same index, one by one for all buttons